# In Go, is a structure pointer not a reference type?

Tags: pointers, go, struct

I don't understand the behavior of Go variables. I want you to tell me. See the example implementation below.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func pointer(ip *Num) {
    fmt.Printf("pointer type [%T] : %p\n", &ip, &ip)
}

func pointerpointer(ip **Num) {
    fmt.Printf("pointerpointer type [%T] : %p\n", ip, ip)
}

func main() {
    pnum := &Num{i: 3}
    fmt.Printf("main type [%T] : %p\n", &pnum, &pnum)
    pointer(pnum)
    pointerpointer(&pnum)
}

type Num struct {
    i int
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/LxDAgopxeh0

- result

```
main type [**main.Num] : 0x40c138
pointer type [**main.Num] : 0x40c148
pointerpointer type [**main.Num] : 0x40c138
```

I store the struct Num pointer as a variable [pnum]. The address that can be acquired when this is passed to the pointer function is different from the address that can be acquired in the main function. Why??

It has been confirmed that the same address as the main function can be obtained by referring to the pointer pointer as the pointerpointer function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`pnum`, in `main`, is an actual variable: a box, floating in memory, containing a pointer of type `*Num`.

```
 0x40c138
+--------+
|    *---|--->
+--------+
```

To what does `pnum` point?  Well, `Num{i: 3}` created an unnamed variable, floating in memory somewhere.  We haven't printed it.  I [modified your Playground example to add one more `fmt.Printf` call](https://play.golang.org/p/nO1FjtFpMs0) to find out:

```
main type [**main.Num] : 0x40c138
pnum points to [*main.Num] : 0x40e020
```

or:

```
 0x40c138       0x40e020
+--------+     +--------+
|    *---|---> |  i: 3  |
+--------+     +--------+
```

Now let's move on: `main` calls `pointer`, passing to it the *value* stored in `pnum`—the `0x40c138` value which lets the computer find the box holding the unnamed instance holding `i=3`.  This value is stored in memory somewhere.  Where is that somewhere?  Why, it's the number you printed, because you print `&ip`.  Fortunately the Playground is very deterministic, so it's also the one I printed:

```
pointer type [**main.Num] : 0x40c148
```

So we can add another box to our drawing:

```
 0x40c138       0x40e020
+--------+     +--------+
|0x40e020|---> |  i: 3  |
+--------+     +--------+
                   ^
 0x40c148          |
+--------+         |
|0x40e020|---------+
+--------+
```

Now `pointer` returns, discarding the box at `0x40c148` that holds `0x40e020`, and you call `pointerpointer`, passing `&pnum` as a value.  Function `pointerpointer` now runs with a box at some location.  Where is that location?  We don't know; we never print it.  We do print what's *in* the box at that location, and what's *in* the box is `0x40c138`:

```
 0x40c138       0x40e020
+--------+     +--------+
|0x40e020|---> |  i: 3  |
+--------+     +--------+
    ^
    |
 ????????
+--------+
|0x40c138|
+--------+
```

We can [add one more `fmt.Printf` to the program to find where this last box actually is in memory](https://play.golang.org/p/mxETZ2TrCUp) and run again:

```
pointerpointer's &ip is [***main.Num] : 0x40c150
```

so replace the eight question marks  with `0x40c150`.

The overall rule here is simple enough: *Every variable has some existence somewhere, unless the compiler can optimize it away.*  Taking the *address* of the variable, with `&x`, tends to prevent the compiler from optimizing the variable itself away.  The *type* of `&x` is `pointer to ___` where the blank is the type of `x`.  The *value* of `&x` is the address of the variable.

In this case, you

- made an anonymous (unnamed) `Num` instance,
- took its address (forcing the compiler to put it into memory somewhere), and
- set a variable `pnum` to that value

(all in the first line of `main`).  Then you took the address of `pnum` itself, which means `pnum` also has to live somewhere in memory.  Those are the two boxes we drew initially.  You printed that address's type and value on your second line.

You then passed the value stored in `pnum` to `func pointer`, which stored the value in a variable.  So that created another, separate variable, which has its own address.

Without worrying about what function `pointer` did, you then passed the *address* of `pnum` to `func pointerpointer`.  This address is a value, and `pointerpointer` stored that value in a variable.  This, too, created another separate variable.

Throughout all of this, the address of the anonymous `Num` with `i=3` never moved.  Neither did the address of `pnum` itself.

Comment: Thank you very much. The understanding of values and addresses (actually hexadecimal "values") allocated in memory has been deepened.

The detailed diagram was very helpful for my understanding.

Comment: Note, by the way, that in the past, and maybe someday again in the future, some computers don't use simple linearly-addressed memory. Go should be able to run on such systems, but there, `%p` might print *two* hexadecimal numbers, or something (that's what C runtime systems did with segmented memory on 80286 machines).

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is:

Pointers are passed by Value.

The function `pointer` receives a copy of the memory address. It stores that copy somewhere (possibly its own stack, or something).

The memory address is just a number.

If you define a number in `main` and take its address, and then you pass that number to another function and take *its* address, should you expect both addresses to be the same?

Answer (score 4):

> In Go, is a structure pointer not a reference type?

No, simply because there **are** **no** **reference** **types** in Go.

There are a few types with reference *semantics*, slices being the most prominent example, but even a slice is a value type and not a reference type.

Pointers in Go a plain values and really machine level addresses. When you pass around a memory address there is no "reference stuff" going on. And if you store the memory address in a variable you can take the address of that variable. Again nothing referency-like. It's values all the way down in Go.

It is basically like in C.

Comment: I understand that memory addresses are just values. It would be helpful if you could tell me more about what reference _semantics_ mean. Now, I think reference _semantics_ and reference type as the same.

The following is an example implementation where slice is a reference type.

https://play.golang.org/p/t0hC2563Ucz

Comment: @TsujiDaishiro A slice is a view into an array. The view itself is a value: If you pass a slice of length 5 into a function and the function shortens its copy of the slice to length 3 the calling function still has a slice of length 5: The slice as view itself is a value and is copied. You can access the elements of the underlying array through a slice and this is where slices show reference semantic: The individual elements of a slice (not the slice itself) might be shared and thus behave reference-like.

Comment: @TsujiDaishiro In your example both slices (the one in main and the copy in pow) are distinct value like slices but they both reference the same elements of the backing array. When you do `a[i] = a[i]*a[i]` you do not do anything to the slice itself, you manipulate elements of the backing array. The backing array is shared between main and pow. Thats why slices have "reference semantic" as the main reason to use a slice is to access the shared/referenced elements of the backing array.

Comment: I understand the concept that slice is a reference to an array. It was very helpful because I wasn't very conscious of it. I would like to deepen my understanding of detailed behavior while writing code. Thank you.